# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect.SomeBean [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I never used Spring AOP and trying to configure my first bean. It seems that I configured it properly, but I get an exception that the bean is not found.

My aspect is –

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class IdentificationAspect {

    @Before("execution(* ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect.SomeBean.*(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("logBefore() is running!");
        System.out.println("hijacked : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        System.out.println("******");
    }
}
```

And my bean that AOP doesn't find is -

```
package ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SomeBean {

    public void printSmth() {
       System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }

}
```

I've got the following exception -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect.SomeBean [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
                at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:301)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:207)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getFallbackPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:358)
                at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.matches(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:255)
                at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:208)
                at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:262)
                at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:294)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:117)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:87)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:68)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:356)
                at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:319)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:412)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1629)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:162)
                ... 165 more
```

I have following maven dependencies -

```
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.3</version>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.3</version>
              </dependency>
```

And my spring applicationContext.xml configuration is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<bean id="someBean" class="ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect.SomeBean">
</bean>
```

**UPDATE** 
I added to my Spring configuration line

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect"/>
```

but still same message. I also tried to annotate different ways - if I don't specify the bean i.e. write -

```
@Before("execution(* ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect.*.*(..))")
```

instead

```
@Before("execution(* ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect.SomeBean.*(..))")
```

I have no error on loading, but aop method is not invoked.

I also tried to annotate like this

```
@Before("this(ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect.SomeBean) and execution(* printSmth(..))")
```

but with same result - no match for this type name. Any more ideas??

Comment: you missed to add bean IdentificationAspect in configuration file

Answer (score 27):

I have the same problem as you and I've solved mine. I give you two suggestions, you can try it out.
Please modify the @Before annotation in the aspect class as one of the following:

`@Before("execution(* ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect.SomeBean.logBefore(..))")`

or

`@Before("execution(* ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect.SomeBean..*(..))")`

Hope it helps.

Comment: For me, changing from ".*" to "..*" solved the problem I had when deploying in JBoss 7. But can you explain why "..*" is needed? (".*" worked just fine in my standalone unit tests)

Comment: @caprica I guess the first '.' is a dot itself but the second '.' is a wildcard matching any character and '*' means matching any number. So `SomeBean..*(..)` means matching all methods of `SomeBean` like `SomeBean.methodA(..)` or `SomeBean.methodB(..)`.

Answer (score 4):

you lose the class.

`@Before("execution(* ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect.SomeBean.*(..))")`

In your way, "somebean" is a package, the * after it is a method, and you should put classes
between them.
You can do it like

`@Before("execution(* ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect.SomeBean.* .*(..))")`

or

`@Before("execution(* ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect.SomeBean..*(..))")`

Answer (score 1):

To run successfully, In your spring applicationContext.xml configuration file add

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect"/>
```

As you used `@Component` annotation in SomeBean class

Update:

try by adding method name to @Before:

```
@Before("execution(* ru.sbt.filial.cards.aspect.SomeBean.logBefore(..))")
```

Comment: I added, but still same message. I also tried to annotate different ways - if I don't specify the bean name -